# Why am I getting error Class not found even if the class does exist and is correctly namespaced

Tags: php, laravel, package, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to develop a package with will be required by some of our applications. However, I am unable to test the package when I require it using composer inside an application.

The package has the following composer.json:

```json
{
    "name": "armcanada/target-horaire",
    "type": "library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Anthony Duhaime",
            "email": "aduhaime@armcanada.ca"
        }
    ],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Armcanada\\TargetHoraire\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

The package has the following directory structure and has the following testing class:
[image: Directory structure and test class]

The package is require in another application in the composer.json:

```json
"require": {
    "armcanada/target-horaire": "dev-master"
}
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../target-horaire"
        }
    ]
```

Finally, I am importing the class and calling the `test()` method:

```php
use Armcanada\TargetHoraire\Models\Timeline;

...

dd((new Timeline())->test());
```

It result with the following error:
`"Class 'Armcanada\TargetHoraire\Models\Timeline' not found"`

I have tried to `composer dumpautoload` in both the application and the package, still has no effect.

I also tried to delete the vendor folder and the package-lock.json then run `composer install`, I am now getting the error:
`include(/app/vendor/composer/../armcanada/target-horaire/src/Models/Timeline.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`. However, the file does exist:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did it actually get installed?

Comment: Yes, I can see it in my vendor folder

Comment: if you look in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` do you see the namespace?

Comment: Yes, it is set like this: `'armcanada\\TargetHoraire\\' => array($vendorDir . '/armcanada/target-horaire/src'),`

It should be Armcanada with a capital A, why is composer-dumpaotoload not fixing this? What should I do?

Comment: interesting ... would expect it to be `Armcanada\\...` not `armcanada\\...`; kinda odd

Comment: If I delete the line and run `composer dumpautoload`, it add the line back with armcanada\\

Comment: Is the package being symlinked when you install? I'm wondering if the path is correct due to it being a local package. [Path type repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) docs.

Comment: Just to ask the dumb stuff: does the file you are using it in (that with the `dd` call) include the autoloader?

Comment: Yes the package is correctly simlinked, as if I make a change in the package, I see the change in the vendor folder of the application.

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot

```
extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

in `Timeline.php

and if using autoloading, try

```
phpunit --bootstrap src/autoload.php
```

Comment: It is not a test case, it is simply a class that I created to verify that I can use my package when it is required by another application.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Why should adding the `extend`  resolve the given error message?